# setTimeout & pop-up modal

Tags: javascript

Привет!
Новичок, практикуюсь, пишу чат на JS.

Нужно сделать выпадающее окно со смайлами. Наводим на иконку - появилось окно, убираем, даем польз. секунду вернуться, выключаем окно. Похожая штука как в vk.com

Собственно, код

```js
  // Hovers

var modal = {
    isActive: false,
    elem: $('.dropdown-smiles'),
    trigger: $('.toggle-smiles'),
    activate: function() {
        this.elem.show();
        this.isActive = true;
        this.trigger.addClass("shown");
    },
    deactivate: function() {
        this.elem.hide();
        this.isActive = false;
        this.trigger.removeClass("shown");
    },
};

function checkHovered() {
    $(document).mouseout(function(e){
        if (!modal.elem.is(e.target) && modal.elem.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            modal.deactivate();
        }
    });
};

modal.trigger.mouseenter(function(){
    modal.activate();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        checkHovered()
    },1000)
});
```

Нужна идея, как правильно использовать checkHovered и setTimeout

Спасибо!

Comment: `$(document).mouseout(function(e){...})` не вызывает функцию, это код просто добавляет обработчик